# Mysql 3 tables 2 joins

Tags: mysql, sql

The goal is to update the `order_items` table and then the column `transportcost`.

```
Table test.inserttest2
- Rows: 480 000
 - Order table
 - Column: Ordernumber and Country


Table test.inserttest3
- Rows: 2 600 000
 - Order items
 - Column: Ordernumber, SKU and Transportcost

Table transportcost
- Rows: 17 000
- a global list of transport price
- Column: SKU, Country, Transportprice
```

Before i make a update statement i do a select statement to check if i get the right fields:
 - 64seconds
 - Rows:62 000

```
SELECT
  a.ordernumber,
  b.country,
  b.transportprice
FROM test.inserttest3 a
INNER JOIN transportcost AS b
  ON a.sku = b.sku
WHERE a.system_created > '2017-12-01'
```

I get a list like this back:

```
17004706    Germany 3.00
17004706    France  6.00
17004706    Netherlands 3.00
17004706    Belgium 3.00
17004706    Austria 4.00
17004706    Italy   5.00
17004706    Switzerland 1.00
17004706    UK  8.00
17004706    Spain   4.00
17004706    Poland  4.00
17004706    Norway  9.00
17004706    Denmark 5.00
17004706    Sweden  6.00
17004706    Czech   4.00
17004706    Finland 6.00
17004706    Ireland 3.00
```

The next step is to use this info for the `order_items` table. Here it goes wrong this is what i have tried but after running these query's for 8 hours i stop them..

```
SELECT
  ps2.ordernumber,
  ps2.sku,
  ps2.country,
  ps2.transportprice
FROM test.inserttest2 aa
JOIN (SELECT
  a.ordernumber,
  b.sku,
  b.country,
  b.transportprice
FROM test.inserttest3 a
INNER JOIN transportcost AS b
  ON a.sku = b.sku
WHERE a.system_created > '2017-12-01') ps2
  ON aa.odernumber = ps2.ordernumber
WHERE aa.country = ps2.country
AND aa.system_created > '2017-12-01'
;
```

.

```
SELECT
  b.sku,
  b.country,
  b.transportcost
FROM test.inserttest3 AS a
INNER JOIN test.inserttest2 AS aa
  ON aa.ordernumber = a.ordernumber
INNER JOIN transportcost AS b
  ON a.sku = b.sku
WHERE aa.country = b.country
AND a.system_created > '2017-12-01'

;
```

Comment: You can try moving your `WHERE` conditions in the `ON` clause for better performance. With INNER JOINs, using ON should perform better than WHERE.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You want to update the order items table that you call `inserttest3` with the transport price of the `transportcost` table. For this to happen you try a query first. That sounds simple: just join the tables.
2. You want to restrict this to orders and order items created after 2017-12-01. With a proper database it is not possible to insert order items before orders, so we can restrict this to *orders* created after 2017-12-01.

The query:

```
select
  io.ordernumber,
  io.sku,
  io.transportcost as cost_wrong,
  t.transportprice as cost_right
from test.inserttest2 o 
join test.inserttest3 io on io.ordernumber = o.ordernumber
join transportcost t on t.sku = io.sku and t.country = o.country
where o.system_created > date '2017-12-01';
```

So the date is our only parameter to restrict the amount of data to read. You should have an index on this column hence. Possible indexes:

```
create index idx_o on inserttest2 (system_created, ordernumber, country);
create index idx_io on inserttest3 (ordernumber, sku);
create index idx_t on transportcost (sku, country, transportprice);
```

Comment: Thank you! The index was the problem. The query is not right yet. I get double ordernumber that's good but i get double sku with the same odernumber..
`16000020 619256 3.00
16000020 619256 3.00
16000020 619256 3.00`

Comment: The query should be fine. There are either two records for the same `ordernumber` in `inserttest2` or two records for the same `ordernumber` and `sku` in `inserttest3` or two records for the same `sku` and `country` in `transportprice`. (All these should be forbidden by primary keys or unique constraints, but it seems they are not.)